# Where does Flutter andoid emulator save file to Windows local disk with path_provider?

Tags: json, flutter, file

Seriously, I can't find the answer to this anywhere. You'd think it would be one of the first things to explain about the path_provider package. I can't find my json file anywhere.

I even searched my entire hard drive using the path it gives me when printing to debug console: /data/user/0/com.example.word_count_tracker/app_flutter but it didn't find anything. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Well the path you are getting as the output to console is the path it is using on the virtual device.
Note that this path doesn’t necessarily correspond to an actual path on your PC.

To view the files from your emulator, go to Android Studio, then
**View -> Tools Window -> Device File Explorer**

Generally speaking the place where these files are stored in your PC would be:
`C:\\<username>\.android\avd`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have specified originally that I'm actually using VSCode rather than Android Studio. Is it the same then?

Comment: Then there isn’t a direct way to access the device files, however you may use ADB shell via CMD to browse the device via commandline. You will find lots of threads on Stackoverflow regarding it’s usage.

Comment: okay then. thanks anyway.